# What version of Windows server is needed for RemoteApp functionality?

Tags: windows, remoteapp

We have a Windows desktop app that we want to make available over the Internet to a few users. What version of Windows Server do I need for that RemoteApp functionality?

I tried to figure this out via Microsoft's website, but I couldn't get a clear bead on how exactly what YEARS (2008, 2012, etc.) and/or what EDITIONS (Data Center vs. Standard vs. Foundation vs. Essentials) of Windows Server support RemoteApp stuff.

Answer (score 2):

RemoteApp is supported in Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: In Server 2008, it's in Standard, Enterprise and DC. In 2012 it's in Standard and DC.

Comment: For Server 2008 and 2008R2: Datacenter and Enterprise have the most extensive support for Remote Desktop roles. Standard, Foundation, and HPC have some support. Itanium and Web do not support being a Remote Desktop Session Host.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also, EE has been deprecated in W2K12, right?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yup.